# Excel Sub or function not defined

Tags: excel, vba

This might just be a sanity check, but I'm getting Sub or Function not defined. I want to use this on a worksheet to find the longest string inside a selected range.

```
Public Function LongestString(searchRange)
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rRng As Range

    Dim longText As String
    Dim longLen  As Integer

    longText = searchRange(0, 0).Value
    longLen = Len(searchRange(0, 0).Value)

    For Each rCell In searchRange.Cells
        'Debug.Print rCell.Address, rCell.Value
        If (Len(rCell.Value) > longLen) Then
            longText = rCell(0, 0).Value
            longLen = Len(searchRange.Cells(0, 0).Value)
        End If
    Next rCell

    LongestString = longText
End Function
```

Comment: `searchRange` is what?  And `Cells()` has 1-based parameters: 0 will cause an error.

Comment: @PyschoData - is this a typo? The function receives a `testRange` variable, but uses `searchRange` in its code

Comment: FYI a regular (array) formula can do this: e.g. `=MAX(LEN(A1:C6))` entered with Ctrl+Shift+Enter

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module, run `Debug>Compile`, and let us know how it goes...

Comment: @Roberto Yeah that was a typo.

Comment: I added option explicit and compiled. It didnt complain of anything (I corected the 'testRange' vs 'searchRange' issue first)

Comment: Are you declaring this in a Module?

Comment: There were two things wrong: 1-the 1 based parameters and 2- I have 'Len(searchRange.Cells(0, 0).' where I should have 'Len(rCell.Cells(0, 0).'

Comment: @rheitzman I added a module to the workbook I'm in. Unless someone knows how to use a function on a worksheet from a Personal.xlsb Module ;P but thats for another question if I ask it

Comment: Also to any who might end up here look for the Personal.xlsb solution as well you have to reference it as 'Personal.xlsb!LongestString(*Range*)' if it's stored in personal. It doesn't try to auto-complete it, but it works when you type it all the way in and press enter

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling this function? 
Are you calling it from another function and passing in the object searchRange? e.g

```
theString = LongestString("B1:C55")
```

I'd also declare the object type of the SearchRange and the data type you want returned from the function  as well, e.g:

```
Public Function LongestString(searchRange as Range) as string
```

Also replace "longLen = Len(searchRange.Cells(0, 0).Value)" in your FOR loop with longLen = Len(rcell(0, 0).Value) so you get the length of the cell you are currently looking at. The finished code should look like this (and you may need to compile it to see it)

```
Public Function LongestString(searchRange As Range) As String
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rRng As Range

    Dim longText As String
    Dim longLen  As Integer

    longText = searchRange(0, 0).Value
    longLen = Len(searchRange(0, 0).Value)

    For Each rCell In searchRange.Cells
        'Debug.Print rCell.Address, rCell.Value
        If (Len(rCell.Value) > longLen) Then
            longText = rCell(0, 0).Value
            longLen = Len(rCell(0, 0).Value)
        End If
    Next rCell

    LongestString = longText
End Function
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this is an answer but, I'm going to a worksheet and typing '=LongestString(' *Selects range with mouse* ')' *Enter*